Android Java: RecyclerView not show enough item
I have an RecyclerView , i'm trying to display a list of item.

My list has 10 item but it just show 8 items. I tried to debug it and after item which have postion is 7, it doesn’t do anything and dosen't continue to inspect variable.
I think my problem is my data so i tried do
      ProductPreview item = newProductItemArrayList.get(position + 2);

and it show correct item but it still just show 8 item so my data have no error. I don't know where i do wrong.
Adapter:
public class Adapter_ProductPreviewRclView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder_ProductPreviewRclView> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ProductPreview> newProductItemArrayList;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder_ProductPreviewRclView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder_ProductPreviewRclView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_preview_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder_ProductPreviewRclView holder, int position) {
        ProductPreview item = newProductItemArrayList.get(position + 2);
      ...
        holder.rootLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {
           ...
        });
        Bitmap logoBitmap = item.getBitmapLogo();
        if (logoBitmap == null) {
            holder.logo.setImageBitmap(null);
            Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            executor.execute(() -> {
                Bitmap bitmap = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(item.getLogo());
                handler.post(() -> {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        holder.logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        item.setBitmapLogo(bitmap);
                    } else {
                        holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_image_broke);
                    }

                });
            });
        } else {
            holder.logo.setImageBitmap(logoBitmap);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newProductItemArrayList.size();
    }
}

Others:
 productListRclView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
 productListRclView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
 productsAdapter = new Adapter_ProductPreviewRclView(getApplicationContext(), productList);


After i updated my data , i tried  : productsAdapter = new Adapter_ProductPreviewRclView(getApplicationContext(), productList);  or             productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it dosen't work.
Thanks for your helps;

Does your recyclerview scroll at all? Do you expect your items to be in a vertical list or in a grid?

@StarterPack no ,it dosen't scroll. I tried if (position == newProductItemArrayList.size() - 1) {             Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             return;         } , nothing is show. I debugged it and it stop at postion = 7.

maybe it doesn't scroll because its somehow "untouchable"...? e.g. covered by some invisible, but clickable View, which hijack MotionEvents? does onClick work? also line setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) is very suspicous, is it needed, is there a reason for placing it there...? also try with other LayoutManager (linear e.g.). generally: plenty of possibilities what could go wrong, adapter looks fine, you should post some more code, XMLs...

you are using position + 2 hence while you at 0th index you are getting 0+2 i.e 3rd index of the list. Hence the 0th and 1st index of the list is not visible.

I realized that i did setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) so it not show enough item ,i delete it and it work. Thanks a lot.
